# How to force PHP not to destroy the Latin-Ext setup?

Tags: php, html, fonts

**BACKGROUND**

I am building a site in the Portuguese language in which the top menu bar is basically supposed to be pulled for every page. This cannot be done in HTML so I chose the PHP INCLUDE option to pull and insert the menu.php file on every HTML page of content I have.

**SITUATION**

After CPaneling my account on the server to PHP 7 and managing to make the PHP Include function flawlessly inside a DIV, including making the CSS3 menu dropdown in 3 levels, I saw that the files were not showing the accents of the Portuguese language, no matter if I used safe fonts, google fonts in latin-ext, etc.

I then tested the menu in HTML only and presented itself without a problem, but every time I pull it from the server in PHP, it a question mark on any special character (yes, I coded the latin-ext LINK tag directly from google fonts)
The server is in the same country I am, Portugal, so the locale should not be a problem.

I don't really know why the PHP continues to ignore / override the setting I have. Here are the codes (I deleted the google fonts and just left websafe fonts to test, same thing happens).

***INDEX.PHP***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="menucontainer">
<?php include 'menu.php';?>
</div>

<div>
this is test writting
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

***MENU.PHP***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="menucontainer">

<ul>
    <li class="parent"><a href="#">A - E</a>
    <ul class="child">
            <li><a href="#">Alfabetos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Alquimia</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bibliografia</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Chakras</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cores</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cristais</a></li>
            <li class="parent"><a href="#">Datas<span class="expand">»</span></a>
                <ul class="child">
                <li><a href="#">Celebrações Pagãs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Cronologia Lusitana</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Cronologia Natal</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Eclipses Lunares</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Eclipses Solares</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Esbaths</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Luas Azuis</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Luas Negras</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sabbaths</a></li>
                </ul>
            <li><a href="#">Discografia</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Elementos</a></li>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent"><a href="#">F - L</a>
    <ul class="child">          
        <li><a href="#">Fauna</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Flora</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Incenso</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Locais</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent"><a href="#">M - R</a>
    <ul class="child">          
        <li><a href="#">Medicinas</span></a>
        <li><a href="#">Metais</a></li>
        <li class="parent"><a href="#">Mitologias<span class="expand">»</span></a>
            <ul class="child">
            <li><a href="#">Mitologia Aborígene</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mitologia Africana</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mitologia Ameríndia</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mitologia Azteca</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mitologia Basca</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mitologia Celta</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mitologia Coreana</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mitologia Egípcia</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mitologia Etrusca</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mitologia Grega</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mitologia Haitiana</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mitologia Hindu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mitologia Inca</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mitologia Japonesa</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mitologia Letã</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mitologia Lusitana</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mitologia Maia</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mitologia Mesopotâmica</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mitologia Nórdica</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mitologia Persa</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mitologia Polinésia</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mitologia Romana</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        <li><a href="#">Numerologia</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Óleos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Oráculos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Protocolo</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent"><a href="#">S - Z</a>
    <ul class="child">
        <li><a href="#">Simbolos</span></a>
        <li><a href="#">Tradições Pagãs</span></a>
        <li class="parent"><a href="#">Utensilios <span class="expand">»</span></a>
            <ul class="child">
            <li><a href="#">Altar</span></a>
            <li><a href="#">Athames</span></a>
            <li><a href="#">Bolas de Cristal</span></a>
            <li><a href="#">Boline</span></a>
            <li><a href="#">Caldeirões</span></a>
            <li><a href="#">Cálices</span></a>
            <li><a href="#">Capas e Robes</span></a>
            <li><a href="#">Castiçais</span></a>
            <li><a href="#">Espelhos Negros</span></a>
            <li><a href="#">Grimórios</span></a>
            <li><a href="#">Joalheria</span></a>
            <li><a href="#">Marcadores a Quente</span></a>
            <li><a href="#">Penas e Tintas</span></a>
            <li><a href="#">Prato de oferendas</span></a>
            <li><a href="#">Tiaras</span></a>
            <li><a href="#">Toalhas de Altar</span></a>
            <li><a href="#">Varinhas</span></a>
            <li><a href="#">Vassouras</span></a>
            <li><a href="#">Velas</span></a>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>   
    <li class="parent"><a href="#">Créditos</span></a>      
    <li class="parent"><a href="#">In Memorium</span></a>       
    <li class="parent"><a href="#">Links</span></a>     
    <li class="parent"><a href="#">Aviso Legal</span></a>       
</ul>
<br><br>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

***STYLE.CSS***

```
body
{margin:0}

.menucontainer
{background-color: black;}

.parent 
{display: block;
position: relative;
float: left;
line-height: 30px;
background-color: black;
border-right:#CCC 1px solid;
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
margin: auto;
}

.parent a
{margin: 10px;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-decoration: none;
}

.parent:hover > ul 
{display:block;
position:absolute;
}

.child 
{display: none;
color: #FFFFFF;
}

.child li 
{background-color: black;
color: #FFFFFF;
line-height: 30px;
border-bottom:#fff 1px solid;
border-right:#fff 1px solid;
width:100%;
}

.child li a
{color: #fff;}

ul
{list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0px;
color: #FFFFFF;
min-width:11em;
background-color:black;
}

ul ul ul
{left: 100%;
top: 0;
margin-left:1px;}

li:hover 
{background-color: green;}

.parent li:hover 
{background-color: green;}

.expand
{font-size:12px;
float:right;
margin-right:5px;}
```

Any help highly appreciated.

Best regards
Luis Lima

Comment: Why does your menu file contain a whole HTML page with doctype, head and body? You should only have a HTML fragment with just the parts that fit into the place where you include it with PHP.

Comment: Never worked with php before. Would that have caused the issue?